# Windows Phone 8.1: loading a BitmapImage at runtime

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have little experience in programming with C# + XAML environment for Windows Phone 8.1. Recently I have been working on an app which load at runtime image and audio resources. Though I have not problems with audio, I cannot be able to load the images. I have already tried many proposed solutions but without success.

Basically in my MainPage.xaml file I have this line:

`<Image Source="{Binding Portrait}"/>`

and in the relative C# code I wrote:

`using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
...
Portrait.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Portraits/path/to specific/portrait.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));`

When I run the application, a NullReferenceException is thrown and I am almost sure it is thrown because the Source is set to `null`.
I checked the path and I am totally sure that it is correct, moreover I set the Resource Build Action to Content (I tried also with Embedded Resource).

I kept the context simple but tell me if more details are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression

```
Portrait.Source = new BitmapImage(...);
```

implies that you have declared the `Portrait` property as `Image`, like

```
public Image Portrait { get; set; }
```

Besides that the property value isn't initialized and `Portrait` is `null` when the assignment is made, the property should actually be of type `ImageSource` (or `BitmapSource`) because `ImageSource` is the type of the `Image.Source` property that you bind in XAML:

```
public ImageSource Portrait { get; set; }
```

and you should assign it like this:

```
Portrait = new BitmapImage(...);
```

Comment: it works perfectly now, thank you very much for the help sir.